# Arbitrary-strings using getline

Tags: c, allocation, bubble-sort

So basically what my program did before i had to change it so that it would accept arbitrary values, was to take x-amount of words and the size of the words would also be arbitrary. (both are user inputted). I did this via a multiArray.
Then sorted according to alphabetical-order.

I'm just going to put it out there as my code is shit and I'm very unfamiliar with the usage of arbitrary-strings and pointers. `I've` `read up on it in the manual` but the concept needs to sink in a little bit first i believe. Anyhow, I get the error: "Abort trap: 6" when i run the program. Could anyone please help me fix this problem so that i can see how the code would look like if it was actually working, i think that would help me understand both pointers and allocating memory a lot better. Forever in debt if you do.

Current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_LENGTH 10
int main(){ //8

  char *name;
  char tname[] = {0};
  char temp[] = {0};
  int i=0, j=0, n=0;
  ssize_t bytes_read;
  size_t bytes_number;


  printf("Enter the amount of words you want to input: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  printf("Enter %d words: ",n);

  bytes_number = MAX_LENGTH;
  name = (char *) malloc (bytes_number+ 1);
  bytes_number = 0;
  bytes_read = getline(&name, &bytes_number, stdin);

  if (bytes_read == -1){
    puts("ERROR!");
    free(name);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
      strcpy(&tname[i], &name[i]);
  }
  for (i = 0; i < n - 1 ; i++){
      for ( j = i + 1; j < n; j++){
          if (strcmp(&name[i], &name[j]) > 0){
              strcpy(temp, &name[i]);
              strcpy(&name[i], &name[j]);
              strcpy(&name[j], temp);
          }
      }
  }
  printf("\n------------------------------------------\n");
  printf("%-3s %4s %11s\n", "Input","|", "Output");
  printf("------------------------------------------\n");
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
      printf("%s\t\t%s\n", &tname[i], &name[i]);
  }
  printf("------------------------------------------\n");
  }
```

Comment: Just `puts("ERROR!");` and continue is not proper error handling. Why do you cast `malloc()`, does the compiler complain? And also, `char tname[] = {0};` doesn't look like what you want.

Comment: The program compiles fine, but after i've went through the first input-stage, the program crashes. Do you have any solutions in mind?

Comment: Note: Compiles fine without `-Wall` is possibly not really *fine*.

Comment: @Joel You have to redesign your program. You need to store `n` words. But you need to consider: 1. a word cannot be longer than 10 characters, that's the limit you defined. - 2. you try to copy each word into the same variable (see answer of iharob); that's not what you want. - 3. you need to learn about arrays in C too, not only pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
strcpy(&tname[i], &name[i]);
```

is completely wrong, if you just want to copy all the characters, then it's just

```
strcpy(tname, name);
```

which is equivalent to

```
for (size_t i = 0 ; name[i] != '\0' ; ++i)
    tname[i] = name[i];
```

using `strcpy(&tname[i], &name[i])` is wrong because it will copy all the bytes from `name` until `'\0'` is found, at every loop starting at the i-th character.

But this will fail again because `tname` is does not have room, it's an array with just one element.

Since you want to sort the strings, you DO NOT NEED TO COPY them. Just swap the pointers. Also

```
char temp[] = {0};
```

only allocates 1 character, thus

```
strcpy(temp, name);
```

will invoke *Undefined Behavior*.

Try this, maybe it's what you need

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(void)
{
    char **words;
    char *temp;
    int word_count;
    int actual_count;
    char *word;
    size_t length;
    int result;

    printf("Enter the amount of words you want to input: ");
    if (scanf("%d%*c", &word_count) != 1)
        return -1; // Input error
    printf("Enter '%d' words:\n", word_count);

    words = NULL;
    word = NULL;
    result = -1;
    actual_count = 0;
    length = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < word_count ; ++i)
    {
        char **pointer;

        printf("Word(%d) > ", i + 1);

        if ((length = getline(&word, &length, stdin)) <= 0)
            goto cleanup;
        // Grow the array of words
        pointer = realloc(words, (i + 1) * sizeof(*pointer));
        if (pointer == NULL)
            goto cleanup; // Memory Exhausted
        // Now it's safe to overwrite `words'
        words = pointer;

        words[i] = malloc(length);
        if (words[i] == NULL)
            goto cleanup; // Memory Exhausted
        memcpy(words[i], word, length);
        words[i][length - 1] = '\0'; // Replace '\n' with '\0'
        actual_count += 1;
    }

    printf("Input : ");
    for (int i = 0 ; i < actual_count ; ++i)
        printf("%s\t", words[i]);
    printf("\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < actual_count - 1 ; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1 ; j < actual_count ; ++j)
        {
            if (strcmp(words[i], words[j]) <= 0)
                continue;
            temp = words[i];
            words[i] = words[j];
            words[j] = temp;
        }
    }

    printf("Output: ");
    for (int i = 0 ; i < actual_count ; ++i)
        printf("%s\t", words[i]);
    printf("\n");

    result = 0;
cleanup:
    free(word);
    for (int i = 0; i < actual_count ; i++)
        free(words[i]);
    free(words);

    return result;
}
```

Note: This would consider an empty word (made completely of white space characters), as a valid word.

Comment: hmm. the compiler doesn't complain, but i can see the logic behind why it wouldnt work. As i said, i'm terrible at pointers... Thanks for your feedback tho. Do you have any other solutions to my problem as I'm sure it lies within the allocation.

Comment: The compiler doesn't complain because it's valid syntax, but it's incorrect.

Comment: i see. I tried changing my strcpy function and sorting to what you suggested. Still no luck. The program is supposed to sort the words using bubble-sorting and put A infront of B etc.

Comment: Don't i need to use arrays for this? How else would i be able to copy an entire word? I just need the function to assign arbitrary-length strings using user-input. ( getline() in this case).

Comment: The logic in your program is not clear at all, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Joel To copy "*arbitrary length string*" you can use `strdup()` in my example I don't, because if it's already known the length of the string, using `malloc()` + `memcpy()` is more efficient in this case.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will be sure to read up on what these things do in the manual. 
If you want i can give you the original working code without my attempt to create arbitrary strings. Might give you a better idea of my thoughtprocess from the working program -> this attempt i posted. :) Thanks anyway! You are golden!